# Right Justify a GridView Column Based on column.DataType

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, gridview, alignment, datacolumn

I need to right justify all cells in a DataColumn in behind code. 
I'm generating a large number of tables using a repeater, so I can't hard code the style in to the `<td>` elements or the css file (to my knowledge).

Ideally I would catch the relevant columns like this;

> ```
> foreach (DataColumn column in ResultTable.Columns) {
>
>             if (column.DataType == typeof(int))
>             {
>                //Set the column justification to "right"
>             } }
> ```

before the repeater is called, but a little googling leaves me with nothing to put in the if statement. I.e. I can't set the style from behind code.

I found a solution to this using javascript for all cells containing an integer number, but as it uses regex to find integers it won't also right justify the column's header. The result of which looks like this for a typical column;

[image]

In this case, I need "Count" to be aligned right as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue during the Repeater_ItemCreated method. Using a css class to set the alignment.

```
var col = new BoundField
{
 HeaderText = column.ColumnName,
 DataField = column.ColumnName,
};
if(column.DataType == typeof(int))
col.ControlStyle.CssClass = "numericCell";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **GridView** event **RowDataBound**, this event is fired for each row after that row has been data bound. You can use **GridViewRow** to get the row and then use **row.cells[index]** where index is the column number

```
GridViewRow gvr = e.Row;
gvr.Cells[0].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Had a look in to this event and it doesn't quite suit the problem. Perhaps my screenshot was misleading, but I won't know ahead of time what column will contain integers. so I need something like
`gvr.Cells[ColumnThatContainsIntegerValues].HorizontalAlign - HorizontalAlign.Right;` However, I can't get this information within that event.

Comment: I managed to get this working to a degree, although the number of Cells was not always correct.
Have solved the issue with a different approach.